# How to use df.rolling(window, min_periods, win_type='exponential').sum()

Tags: pandas

I would like to calculate the rolling exponentially weighted mean with `df.rolling().mean()`. I get stuck at the `win_type = 'exponential'`.

I have tried other *win_types such as 'gaussian'. I think there would be sth a little different from 'exponential'.

```
dfTemp.rolling(window=21, min_periods=10, win_type='gaussian').mean(std=1)
# works fine
```

but when it comes to 'exponential',

```
dfTemp.rolling(window=21, min_periods=10, win_type='exponential').mean(tau=10)
# ValueError: The 'exponential' window needs one or more parameters -- pass a tuple.
```

How to use `win_type='exponential'`... Thanks~~~

Comment: i think it would be better to use `pandas.DataFrame.ewm` for calculating exponential moving averages. Documentation here --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Comment: @mohanys Thanks. That would be one way. But I would figure it out about `df.rolling.mean`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced same issue and [asked it on Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017577):

Got [the following answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017952/211923):

```
x.rolling(window=(2,10), min_periods=1, win_type='exponential').mean(std=0.1)
```

You should pass tau value to `window=(2, 10)` parameter directly where `10` is a value for tau.

I hope it will help! Thanks to @MaxU

Comment: Can we have a little more explanation on tau and the window tuple? Pandas has poor documentation on this. Comparing this answer to the question, for window=(2,10), the tau value of 10 seems to be the size (or min size) of the window. The first value; 2, must relate to decay? What would window be for 20 periods where the exponential decay halved each period?

Comment: `ValueError: exponential window requires tau`. copy-pasting this line doesn't work, what's the fix?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily implement any kind of window by definining your kernel function.

Here's an example for a backward-looking exponential average:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Kernel function ( backward-looking exponential )
def K(x): 
    return np.exp(-np.abs(x)) * np.where(x<=0,1,0)

# Exponenatial average function
def exp_average(values):
    N = len(values)
    exp_weights = list(map(K, np.arange(-N,0) / N ))
    return values.dot(exp_weights) / N

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [pd.datetime(2020,1,1)]*50 + [pd.datetime(2020,1,2)]*50,
    'x'   : np.random.randn(100)
})

# Finally, compute the exponenatial moving average using `rolling` and `apply`
df['mu'] = df.groupby(['date'])['x'].rolling(5).apply(exp_average, raw=True).values
df.head(10)
```

---

Notice that, if `N` is fixed, you can significantly reduce the execution time by keeping the weights constant:

```py
N = 10
exp_weights = list(map(K, np.arange(-N,0) / N ))

def exp_average(values):
    return values.dot(exp_weights) / N
```

Comment: how do you add the tau parameter to this? :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you should use pass tau to the applied function, e.g., `rolling(d, win_type='exponential').sum(tau=10)`. **Note** that the `mean` function does not respect the exponential window as expected, so you may need to use `sum(tau=10)/window_size` to calculate the exponential mean. This is a BUG of current version Pandas (`1.0.5`).

Full example:

```py
# To calculate the rolling exponential mean
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

window_size = 10
tau = 5
a = pd.Series(np.random.rand(100))
rolling_mean_a = a.rolling(window_size, win_type='exponential').sum(tau=tau) / window_size
```

The answer of @Илья Митусов is not correct. With `pandas 1.0.5`, running the following code raises `ValueError: exponential window requires tau`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.Series(np.arange(10)).rolling(window=(4, 10), min_periods=1, win_type='exponential').mean(std=0.1)
```

This code has many problems. First, the 10 in `window=(4, 10)` is not `tau`, and will lead to wrong answers. Second, `exponential` window does not need the parameter `std` -- only `gaussian` window needs. Last, the `tau` should be provided to `mean` (although `mean` does not respect the `win_type`).

Comment: Thanks Han, what is tau inside the mean()? Thanks

Comment: tau is the decay parameter. Check out details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.exponential.html).