# Apply custom window function in pandas rolling

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions, rolling-computation

I have a DataFrame, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

Now I want to apply a rolling mean, e.g.

```
df.rolling(window=3, win_type=None).mean()
```

which gives me a result with evenly weighted elements.
Now I want to change the window function. I know, that this is possible by passing a string (e.g. `'hann'`) to the `win_type` parameter.

```
df.rolling(window=3, win_type='hann').mean()
```

Now the interesting point for me would be to apply a window function, that uses an exponentially decaying weighting, giving a high weight to the value "on the right" and lower weights to values "further to the left". This should be possible by using `scipy.signal.windows.exponential` and adjusting the parameters. However, I am struggling with passing those parameters as  `win_type` only takes strings.

When I try  `win_type='exponential'` I get `ValueError: exponential window requires tau`.

Can someone tell me how to pass parameters such as `tau` to `win_type` or even create a window function oneself?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57518576/how-to-use-df-rollingwindow-min-periods-win-type-exponential-sum) 
**Important. Solution depends on pandas version.** 
Python common

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

In the case of *tau*=10.
For Pandas='0.24.2'

```py
df.rolling(window=(3,10), win_type='exponential').mean()
```

For Pandas='1.1.3'

```py
df.rolling(window=3, win_type='exponential').mean(tau=10)
```

*Do not hesitate to add other version dependencies.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, copying this exact code still produces 
```
ValueError: exponential window requires tau
```

Comment: Weird. These 3 rows of code work for me. Which versions of pandas and numpy are you using?

Comment: My pandas is 1.1.3

Comment: I used pandas='0.24.2', and after checking with version  1.1.3 I can claim that the solution is version dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with an answer from the link provided by Stepan:
Tau has to be passed in the function call, i.e.

```
df.rolling(window=(3), win_type='exponential').mean(tau=10)
```